# Adding hexadecimal numbers

Tags: assembly, binary, x86, hex

I'm learning Assembly language and have these values in my register.

```
Ebx: FFFF FF75
Ecx: 0000 01A2
```

After performing sub ebx, ecx...I get FFFFFDD3 with SF(1), ZF(0),CF(0),OF(0)

I tried writing this out by hand, but am getting a different answer for the flags. Since it's a (-)-(+) We turn it into (-)+(-) by getting the 2's compliment of Ecx. This gives us FFFF FE5E. Now when we add them together, there's a value that get's carried out. Shouldn't this make the CF flag 1?

Comment: For subtract, the CF flag is treated as a "borrow" flag. With your example sub ebx,ecx, it will only get set if ecx > ebx (treated as unsigned integers).

Comment: Some instruction sets invert the carry out when setting the carry flag  if the operation was subtract, sounds like the processor you are using does that.  The carry in is set and/or inverted, the second operand is inverted if the operation is a subtract going into a add logic, then sometimes the carry out is inverted when saving to the carry flag.